# Compute $E(Y\mid X=m)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The random vector $(X,Y)$ has the following joint distribution

$$P(X=m, Y=n) = {m\choose n} \frac{1}{2^m}\frac{m}{15}$$

where $m=1,\ldots,5$ and $n=0,\ldots,m$. Compute $E(Y\mid X=m)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are confused as to where to start, so here are some guidelines. Fill in the details and do the calculations, or ask if any particular points are unclear.

To find the mean value $E(Y\ |\ X=m)$, you can use that

$$E(Y\ |\ X=m) = \sum_{n=0}^m P(Y=n\ |\ X=m)n,$$

so you need to calculate the conditional probability $P(Y=n\ |\ X=m)$.

You can find this by definition of conditional probability:

$$P(Y=n\ |\ X=m) = \frac{P(Y=n,X=m)}{P(X=m)},$$

You already have the joint probability, so you only need to think about $P(X=m)$. This probability is given as

$$P(X=m) = \sum_{n=0}^m P(X=m,Y=n) = \sum_{n=0}^m\binom{m}{n}\frac{1}{2^m}\frac{m}{15}.$$

This can be hugely simplified.

Comment: I was able to simplify it to $m\choose n$ $/$$\sum^m_{n=0}$ $m \choose n$ but I dont know where to go from there

Comment: @AlexChavez there's a trick here, where you use the binomial formula: If $a,b\geq 0$, then $(a+b)^m = \sum_{n=0}^m \binom{m}{n}a^nb^{m-n}$. What happens if you let both $a=b=1$?

Comment: great thanks!. I don't know if you solved the problem but i  ended up getting $m/2$

Comment: @AlexChavez looks good to me :)